# Поиск файлов в системе на Python

Tags: python, ос, grab

Требуется узнать расположение определенного файла в системе (*он может находиться на любом диске*). Рассматривал множество способов в интернете, но ценного ничего не нашел. Из предположений есть только то, что данный алгоритм использует библиотеку **Grab** и **OS**. Буду очень благодарен за ответ. Так же заранее спасибо, что не проявили безразличие к проблеме.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python

Comment: На любом диске, но путь от корня диска одинаковый?

Comment: @gil9red да, путь от корня диска одинаковый

Comment: @Jack_oS смотрел, результата не принесло по причине непонятной работы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз путь от корня не меняется, попробуйте в цикле пройтись по пути, меняя букву диска.

Пример:

```
import string
import os.path

path_file = ':/Program Files (x86)/JoWooD/Painkiller Resurrection/bin/Resurrection.exe'

for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
    file_name = letter + path_file
    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        print('Found:', file_name)
        break

# Found: E:/Program Files (x86)/JoWooD/Painkiller Resurrection/bin/Resurrection.exe
```

Comment: Направление верное, но цель найти файл в системе, который может лежать в любом месте на одном диске. Это я уже доделаю сам, а так очень благодарен за решение)

Comment: @Developman, пожалуйста :) но в комментах вы о другом писали :) А для поиска можно использовать `glob` с заданным атрибутом `recursive=True`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5a780831079c69cd2351a2249d6c8397c6f27a57/glob__examples/recursive_search.py#L24

Comment: смотрел, только мой мозг не понимает как задать ему поиск на определенный файл, а не расширение

Comment: Вот поиск конкретного файла: `print(glob.glob('E://**/Resurrection.exe', recursive=True))`. У меня вернуло: `['E://Program Files (x86)\\JoWooD\\Painkiller Resurrection\\bin\\Resurrection.exe']`

Comment: какой параметр нужен для "чистого" вывода строки без использования [ ] и ' '? Просто он выводит в не совсем понятном виде а функцию format применить невозможно

Comment: @Developman, `glob.glob` вернет список, вот и работайте с ним как с списком. Можете вывести в цикле, можете, например, достать первый элемент из списка и его вывести, можете в `print` распаковать. Например, `items = glob.glob('E://**/Resurrection.exe', recursive=True)` `print(*items, sep='\n')`. Или `for x in items: print(x)`

Answer (score 0):

поисковик файлов на питон

```
import glob
import os

from tkinter import*

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Поисковик файлов")

ent = Entry()
ent.place(relx = 0.3,rely = 0.4)

lbl = Label(text = "Введите сюда свой запрос")
lbl.place(relx = 0.3,rely=0.3)

def search():
    a= ent.get()
    d = glob.glob(a)
    if len(d)==0:
        lbl_1 = Label(text = "Нету файлов с таким названием")
        lbl_1.place(relx = 0.3,rely=0.6)
    else:
        st_var = Variable(value=d)
        s_listbox = Listbox(listvariable=st_var,height=5)
        s_listbox.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6,width = 375,height = 125)
        scroll = Scrollbar(orient="vertical",command=s_listbox.yview)
        scroll.place(relx=0,rely = 0.6)
        s_listbox["yscrollcommand"]=scroll.set

btn = Button(text = "Начать поиск",command = search)
btn.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.5)

window.mainloop()
```